# why running a maven spring project on intellij giving "connection refused on port" error

Tags: intellij-idea, maven-2, spring-3

[image]

I am running a sample "hello world" spring maven project from my machine and debugger  port is allowing to run or debug the class  also browser gives blank screen[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To debug a maven project:

1. start a maven project in debug mode using 'mvnDebug' command instead of 'mvn'.
   For your case should be:
   **mvnDebug jetty:run**
   It should open a debug port of 8000 by default on your machine.
2. tell your IDE to remotely connect to the running JVM of your server like you did in the picture (make sure you got the correct port).

The connection refused happens because there is no actual running JVM listening on 8081, as described in your picture.

You mentioned that you get a blank screen in the browser. Maybe you also have a misconfiguration in your pom file. The myspringlearning plugin definition doesn't seem right. You should just make sure you:

- have a maven webapp project in your pom.xml (packaging should be war)
- the jetty plugin should automatically pick it by default, on port 8080, just 'mvn jetty:run' in your project root